# Can you get any natural number from 4 by performing given operations?

Tags: co.combinatorics, algorithms, gm.general-mathematics

You can perform the following operations on numbers:

1. divide the number by 2,
2. add 0 or 4 at the end of the number.

Can you get any natural number from 4 by performing only these operations?

So far I have come up with this algorithm to get 4 from any natural number N by performing opposite operations (multiplying by 2, deleting 0 or 4 from the end of the number).

1. Check the last digit of N,

   a. If it's 0 or 4, remove the last
   digit.

   b. If it's neither 0 nor 4, multiply
   N by 2.
2. If N is not 4 go to Step 1.

The problem is I can't prove that this algorithm works for any natural number.

Comment: This has a Collatz feel to it... might be very hard. Or very easy.

Comment: Since the algorithm terminates for the first 3 numbers, it suffices to show that for any N, iterating the algorithm eventually produces a number smaller than N. Then analysing congruences mod 10 shows that only numbers ending in 9 have not became smaller after 4 iterations. But for higher iterations the numbers obtained are now always even, so they don't end in 9, and so eventually any number becomes smaller (I think this can be proved analysing mod 10.000 but have not checked).

Comment: @JoelMoreira Indeed, $\mod 10^4$ works nicely. For smaller powers of $10$ we have a problem with 9; 49, 99; 249, 499, 749, 999 but then they all suddenly get resolved :-)

Comment: @fedja Sounds like you should write an answer (community wiki maybe?).

Comment: @TimothyChow OK, done :-) I guess one can handle it by hand in finite time as well, but writing the program took about 4 minutes, so I decided to resort to the brute force in this case. If somebody sees a slick argument without boring casework, I would be interested, of course.

Answer (score 7):

The following program (in Asymptote, but the syntax is pretty much the same as in C and, I hope, the algorithm is self-explanatory) considers all remainders modulo $10^n$ and prints those for which the steps up to the moment when we remove all $n$ known digits do not allow to conclude that the number got smaller. The printouts for $n=1,2,3$ are as mentioned in the comment. For $n=4$ the program terminates without printing anything.

```
int n=4, M=10^n;

for(int k=0;k<M;++k)
{
int nn=n, MM=M, a=k;
real s=0;
while(nn>0 && s>=-0.0000000001)
{
if(a%10==4 || a%10==0) {a=quotient(a,10);--nn;s-=log(10); MM=quotient(MM,10);}
else {a=(a*2)%MM; s+=log(2);}
}
if(s>0) write(k);
}

pause();
```